# removeClass(); won't work in safari mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, safari

I need help with this, I have been struggeling to get this to work... :

```
btnMenu.on('click', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.addClass('selected');

    if(menu.is(':visible')) {
        alert('visible'); // This works
        $this.removeClass('selected'); // This doesnt work in safari mobile but works everywhere else.
    }

    menu.stop().slideToggle(500, 'easeInOutQuint');

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Thank you

Comment: does `this.className = this.className.replace(/\bselected\b/g, '');` work?

Comment: Unfortunately no... :(

Comment: Hmm.. `alert(this.className); this.classList.remove('selected');`

Comment: I tried to use this $this.toggleClass('selected'); and it still does'nt work in Safari Mobile yet it works everywhere else, that is weird to me...

Comment: does this.classList.remove('selected') work?

Comment: No it didnt work either.

Comment: You can access the code here http://www.tourismeshawinigan.adnhosting.ca/js/script.js

Comment: I have no access to safari.

Answer (score 0):

How about not adding the "selected" first and instead use an else?

```
if(menu.is(':visible')) {
    alert('visible'); // This works
    $this.removeClass('selected'); // This doesnt work in safari mobile but works everywhere else.
} else {
    $this.addClass('selected');
}
```

Or even, based on your code;

```
if(!menu.is(':visible')) {
    $this.addClass('selected');
}
```